# Why the Wonkamobile instead of the Great Glass Wonkavator?

Tags: book-adaptation, willy-wonka-and-chocolate-factory, adaptation

In *Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory*, when Wonka and the remaining Guests exit the Golden Goose Room, they use the Wonkamobile to get to the T.V. Room but why not the Great Glass Elevator as in the Novel?

Comment: Most likely because the movie's makers wanted to keep the elevator as a final "reveal"?

Comment: Or maybe there were constraints (budget, sets, special effects) that prevented showing the elevator traveling sideways, slantways, etc.  Showing it only for the final "Up & Out" trip let them simulate only upward movement.